# table_clone_elements How can I make it copy the class attribute also?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-6

When using the add new  (row) option on the quick tables menu, Tinymce can create a new row . How can I make it also copy the previous rows  classes? currently I have a class on the  elements but when creating a new row the classes are lost on the new row .